# Using pip to install python modules

Tags: python, command-line, pip

I am having trouble installing igraph in Python 3.4

In the Python command (c:\Python34\python.exe) I typed:

```
python -m pip install igraph
```

I get the following return:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1

python -m pip install igraph
            /\
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

This should be run from a `cmd` prompt **not** a python shell.

ipython:

```
In [1]: python -m pip install igraph
  File "<ipython-input-1-6f39be96f483>", line 1
    python -m pip install igraph
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

From bash

```
~$ python -m pip install igraph
Collecting igraph
........
```